# Flutter, How to stay in position after lazy loading

Tags: flutter, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to build a list from http server, and would like to implement page load for large data set.  I tried with lazy_load_scrollview package and follow the example, I can load additional records from the server on End of page, but when new records are loaded, the list jumps up to the first record. How could I avoid this?

```
int totalRecords = 0;
int recordsPerPage = 5;
int currentPage = 1;
int totalPages = 1;

List<dataRecord> dataList = [];
List<dataRecord> fullList = [];
bool isLoading = false;

//class definitions...

class searchClient extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _searchClientState createState() => _searchClientState();
}

class _searchClientState extends State<searchClient> {
  final _searchItemController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dataList = [];
    currentPage = 1;
  }

  List<dataRecord> parseJson(String responseBody) {
    final parsed =
        convert.jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<dataRecord>((json) => dataRecord.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _searchItemController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void loadData() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    if (totalRecords == 0) {
      final response2 = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('http://192.168.0.8:88/searchcustomer_gettotal' +
            '?userID=' +
            globals.userID.toString() +
            '&token=' +
            globals.token +
            '&name=' +
            _searchItemController.text),
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
        },
      );
      Map<String, dynamic> totalMap = convert.jsonDecode(response2.body);
      var total = totals.fromJson(totalMap);
      totalRecords = total.total;
      var t = totalRecords / recordsPerPage;
      if (totalRecords < recordsPerPage) {
        totalPages = 1;
      }else if (totalRecords%recordsPerPage == 0) {
        totalPages = t.round();
      }else{
        var t = totalRecords / recordsPerPage;
        totalPages = t.round()+ 1;
      }
      print(totalRecords);
    }
    ;

    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('http://192.168.0.8:88/searchcustomer' +
          '?userID=' +
          globals.userID.toString() +
          '&token=' +
          globals.token +
          '&name=' +
          _searchItemController.text +
          '&pageno=' +
          currentPage.toString() +
          '&perpage=' +
          recordsPerPage.toString()),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
      },
    );
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
    dataList = parseJson(response.body);
    fullList = List.from(fullList)..addAll(dataList);
  }

  void loadMore() {
    if (currentPage < totalPages) {
      currentPage += 1;
      loadData();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Search Client')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 10, 12, 20),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Search Item'),
              controller: _searchItemController,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 45,
            width: 250,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.teal, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                totalRecords = 0;
                fullList = [];
                loadData();
              },
              child: Text(
                'Search',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          isLoading
              ? Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                )
              : Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 12, 0),
                    child: LazyLoadScrollView(
                      isLoading: isLoading,
                      onEndOfPage: () {
                        loadMore();
                      },
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: fullList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return dataCard(context, fullList, index);
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to add ScrollController to listView to control the scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try removing this widget of your tree

```
Center(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ),
)
```

in order to only have your Scrollview ?

My guess is that since you're calling the `setState` method at load time, your whole widget tree is rebuilt, and when your new datas are fetched the whole `listview` is rebuilt, losing the previous position.

I'll edit my answer with some code if this doesn't fix your problem

Comment: Yes, it works now, thanks.  Just what about if I need a progress indicator when loading data?

Comment: You could either use a Stack to display your loader above your list, or add a loader under your Listview. As long as you don't replace your ScrollView with another widget like you previously did, it will work as expected

Comment: Check out BLoC architecture. You can control every state and act according to that  depending on your needs. For example, you can have states like: objectNotLoaded, loadingRandomObject, loadingMoreRandomObject, randomObjectLoaded, moreRandomObjectLoaded (states for lazy loading) . Then, you can set a blocListener that will show a progress indicator every time it is listening to loadingRandomObject or loadingMoreRandomObject .